# How to add multiple add to cart buttons on one form

Tags: php, html, paypal

I have 16 products, all of which have separate add to cart buttons assigned to them. When a customer enters their desired quantity and then clicks add to cart, the product is added to the shopping cart and the customer is directed to the corresponding paypal shopping cart. I was wondering if there was a way to carry out the same action without having to make individual buttons for each product?

This is the code for one of my buttons:

```
<form target="paypal" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
                        <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
                        <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="93XBL9HZ8D5MG">
                        <table>
                        <tr><td><input type="hidden" name="add" value="1"></td></tr><tr><td>
                        <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="AR.VIN.001 - Unframed">
                        Qty <input type="text" name="quantity" maxlength="5" value="1" style="position: relative; width:30px; height: 23px; top: 25px; left: 35px;">

                            </table>
                        <input type="image" src="./img/button.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal – The safer, easier way to pay online."  style="position:relative; left: 50px; top: 0px;">
                        <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_GB/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
                    </form>'
```

Comment: I’m not sure I understand. Surely you need a button per item? Otherwise how are you going to identify which item a user is adding to the cart?

Comment: Could you show the code that you using? You could stick all the inputs in the same form? Then when one submit button is clicked it will submit the entire form.

Comment: @MartinBean Couldn't you use the input field specifying the amount, name each for the product. Not to sure how the paypal shopping cart works though without seeing some code.

Comment: it works perfectly fine with individual buttons however, my concern is the inconvenience it will cause when i have lets say 50+ products. I was wondering if there was a way to have like 1 add to cart button and  modify it in such a way that it adds the different items to the cart.

Comment: You mean to say that user will be redirected to paypal with the single click that will contain data for all products

Comment: Indeed. So let's say i have 4 products listed on one page, when a user  clicks the add to cart button they are redirected to the paypal page with the product data

Comment: Why would you want to add *all* products in one click?

Comment: What i meant was to have one button function of some sort that will carry out adding all the different items. So instead of having to manually create several buttons for each individual product, i will have one button function that will carry out everything. Therefore i don't have a long line of code that just says button1,button2....button100 instead i have one efficient button function if that makes any sense?

Answer (score 0):

Your title and question seem to have different meanings, so I will answer your title query ( how to add multiple add to cart buttons on one form ).

The simple answer is that you don't. But you can simulate doing this, and I can think of 2 ways of doing this, one with javascript, the other with php.

**PHP way:**

Make all the add to cart buttons link to `index.php?action=add&product_id=4`, and don't show the paypal form on that page. In the corresponding page, you generate the paypal redirect form depending on the product id, and whatever info you want to send, then submit it with javascript. Ideally, you should also make a timer, and add a message like: "You will be redirected to PayPal in 5 secs. If not, click the link below".

**Javascript way:**

Have the paypal form exist on the page, but be hidden. Then, add an `onclick` action on the add to cart buttons, that changes the paypal form input values depending on the button clicked, then submit it with javascript.

---

Personally,  I prefer the PHP way because you have more control. For example, you can save the order before redirecting to PayPal, but this also depends on your needs. The javascript way is more of a hack than a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think i understand what you were looking for. I'm assuming all the products are in a single form. You can use

```
<input type="checkbox" name="productName" value="productId">
```

Add this to every product item on the page.

Then add a single button to add only the selected items to the cart.

```
<button type="submit">Add Selected Items to Cart</button>
```

The form data should now contain only the selected products. Else you can iterate over the selected items using javascript and ajax it to the server.

Doesn't matter this question was asked 4 years back. I chanced upon it looking for add to cart implementation. Hopefully someone finds it helpful. :)